# Scale posts to screen size [div too big for screen]

Tags: html, css

I am developing a blog website and have noticed that the blog posts are not proportionate to different screen sizes. I have mostly developed this on my desktop which has a larger screen compared to my laptop which I also tested it on. I am using the MDL css framework for the front end. Here are some examples of the issue:

[image: Blog posts on the laptop screen]

[image: Blog posts on the desktop]

The top image is the website displayed on the desktop and the bottom image is the website displayed on the laptop. As can be seen from the images, the blog posts on the laptop are considerably larger and not proportionate to the screen size at all. Does anyone have any idea on how to scale down the blog post divs so that it is more proportionate to the laptop screen and other screen sizes?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Media Queries to give different styles to different sized devices.

> *Media queries are a popular technique for delivering a tailored style sheet to different devices.*

```css
/* Set the background color of body to tan */
body {
  background-color: tan;
}

/* On screens that are 992px or less, set the background color to blue */
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  body {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}

/* On screens that are 600px or less, set the background color to olive */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: olive;
  }
}
```